# problem adding cidfont to ghostscript

Tags: fonts, pdf, ghostscript

**PREFACE**

I understand this is a little harder since I can't provide the actual pdf, but the question boils down to a more general ghostscript config question so I don't think the pdf is needed.

---

I have a pdf. I am trying to repair with ghostscript. It is trying to use the font `STHeitiSC-Light` which is supposed to be embedded in the pdf, but it doesn't appear to be correctly embedded. I tried to fix it with  [popplerutils](https://fossies.org/linux/poppler/utils/pdftocairo.1); when I run

```
pdftocairo -pdf bad_pdf.pdf repaired.pdf
```

I get this super informative error message:

> some font thing failed 
> some font thing failed

```
gs -o repaired.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress bad_pdf.pdf
```

I get

> **** Warning: can't process font stream, loading font by the name.
>  Can't find CID font "`STHeitiSC-Light`". 
> Attempting to substitute CID
>   font `/Adobe-Identity` for `/STHeitiSC-Light`, 
>             see `doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution`. 
> The substitute CID font "`Adobe-Identity`" is not provided either. 
>             attempting to use fallback `CIDFont`.See `doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution`. 
> The fallback CID font "`CIDFallBack`"
>   is not provided.
>           Finally attempting to use `ArtifexBullet`.
>         **** Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete.
>         **** File did not complete the page properly and may be damaged

So, I made sure I have STHeitiSC-Light installed on my system. I added a ttf to

`/usr/share/fonts/truetype/STHeitiSC-Light.ttf`

And I updated my cidfmap with

```
/STHeitiSC-Light << /FileType /TrueType /Path (/usr/share/fonts/truetype/STHeitiSC-Light.ttf) /SubfontID 0 /CSI [(Identity) 0] >> ;
```

But the error still persists, so I'm not sure what to do. There is some text in the pdf using this font, I don't even care that the font is preserved, but currently, the pdf is rendered with that text blanked out.

Comment: If nobody else has an idea: Make another pdf with embedded `STHeitiSC-Light`. Using `mutool clean -d` if necessary, identify the embedded font in the original pdf in an editor, and replace with the correct stream from the other pdf. Fixup object table with `pdftk` or whatever comes handy. (It's hard to answer this question without being able to look at the damaged pdf).

Comment: That might fix this particular pdf, but doesn't answer in general how to make ghostscript recognize the installed font and use it